# get the database Name , Creation Date when Database is UNmounted Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Is it possible to get the database name , Creation Date 
when the database is on Startup but **NOT mounted** ? 
when it is mounted we can use this statement :

```
select NAME,CREATED from V$DATABASE ;
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

No.  When unmounted, the only file that has been opened is the parameter file - init or spfile.  The only information there is that which is needed properly allocate memory for the instance, where to write critical logs, and where to find the control file(s).

Comment: besides, you can query some fixed tables of Oracle Database.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - yes, some fixed tables are available when the database is in nomount mode.  Specifically, v$instance.  But do you have one in particular in mind that provides what the OP is after?

Comment: I mean fixed tables with `x$` prefix such as x$kcccf, x$kcbsw, x$kglst .. etc., those are available in nomount mode, but they don't provide exact info what OP want to have unfortunately.